# Duplicate names errors in terraform deploy when depploying for the first time

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront

I have the following terraform cloudfront deployment code, that deploys 2 CDNS for both app and web on my application. They are hosted in their respective S3 buckets on my aws account.

```
locals {
    www_s3_origin_id = "${var.env}.mydomain.net.s3.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com"
    app_s3_origin_id = "app-${var.env}.mydomain.net.s3-website.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com"                      
}

# ##########################################################
# ###  STATIC FILES CDN 
# ##########################################################

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control" "www_mydomain_net_oac" {
  name                              = "${local.www_s3_origin_id}"
  description                       = "${var.env}.mydomain.net OAC"
  origin_access_control_origin_type = "s3"
  signing_behavior                  = "always"
  signing_protocol                  = "sigv4"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "www_mydomain_net" {
  
  aliases = [
    "${var.env}.mydomain.net"
  ]
  
  comment = "${var.env} mydomainNet"

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods = ["PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    compress        = "false"
    default_ttl     = "60"

    forwarded_values {
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }

      query_string = "false"
    }

    max_ttl                = "31536000"
    min_ttl                = "0"
    smooth_streaming       = "false"
    target_origin_id       = "${var.env}.mydomain.net"    
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  # default_root_object = "index.html"
  default_root_object = "/bilans"
  enabled             = "true"
  http_version        = "http2"
  is_ipv6_enabled     = "true"

   
  origin {
    origin_access_control_id = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control.www_mydomain_net_oac.id
    domain_name = local.www_s3_origin_id
    origin_id = local.www_s3_origin_id
  }
  
  price_class = "PriceClass_100"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  retain_on_delete = "false"

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn            = var.certificate_arn
    # acm_certificate_arn            = "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-3:${var.accountId}:certificate/${var.certificateId}"
    cloudfront_default_certificate = "false"
    minimum_protocol_version       = "TLSv1.2_2019"
    ssl_support_method             = "sni-only"
  }
}


##########################################################
###  APP CDN NET
##########################################################

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "app_mydomain_net" {
  
  comment = "${var.env} application CDN for mydomain"

  aliases = [
   "app-${var.env}.mydomain.net"
  ]

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods = ["PATCH", "POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    compress        = "true"
    default_ttl     = "60"

    forwarded_values {
      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }

      query_string = "false"
    }

    max_ttl                = "31536000"
    min_ttl                = "0"
    smooth_streaming       = "false"
    target_origin_id       = "app-${var.env}.mydomain.net"    
    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  default_root_object = "index.html"
  enabled             = "true"
  http_version        = "http2"
  is_ipv6_enabled     = "true"

  origin {
    connection_attempts = "3"
    connection_timeout  = "10"
    domain_name         = local.app_s3_origin_id    
    origin_id           = "app-${var.env}.mydomain.net"
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port                = 80 
      https_port               = 443 
      origin_keepalive_timeout = 5 
      origin_protocol_policy   = "http-only" 
      origin_read_timeout      = 30 
      origin_ssl_protocols     = [
         "TLSv1.2",
      ]
    }
  }

  price_class = "PriceClass_100"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  retain_on_delete = "false"

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn            = var.app_certificate
    cloudfront_default_certificate = "false"
    minimum_protocol_version       = "TLSv1.2_2019"
    ssl_support_method             = "sni-only"
  }
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "app_mydomain_net_allow_access_from_another_account" {
  bucket = var.appnetS3_id
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.app_mydomain_net_policy_bucket_mydomain.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "app_mydomain_net_policy_bucket_mydomain" {
  statement {
    principals {
      type        = "*"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
    ]

    resources = [
      var.appnetS3_arn,
      "${var.appnetS3_arn}/*",
    ]
  }
}
```

When planning I have no errors, but when deploying, I have the following :

Error: creating Amazon CloudFront Origin Access Control (dev.mydomain.net.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com): OriginAccessControlAlreadyExists: An origin access control with the same name already exists.
│   status code: 409, request id: c910d174-26af-4449-a8fd-5d4eb0782960
│
│   with module.ah_cloudfront.aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control.www_mydomain_net_oac,
│   on ../../modules/cloudfront/main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control" "www_mydomain_net_oac":
│   11: resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control" "www_mydomain_net_oac" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: creating CloudFront Distribution: CNAMEAlreadyExists: One or more aliases specified for the distribution includes an incorrectly configured DNS record that points to another CloudFront distribution. You must update the DNS record to correct the problem. For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-restrictions
│   status code: 409, request id: c6b03263-166b-41d7-a69a-1f9d191cc334
│
│   with module.ah_cloudfront.aws_cloudfront_distribution.app_mydomain_net,
│   on ../../modules/cloudfront/main.tf line 93, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "app_mydomain_net":
│   93: resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "app_mydomain_net" {
│

What I've tried so far :

- comment the cloudfront part and deploy, and then redploy uncommenting the cloudfront part
- removing every related item in my tfstate file and manually delete the cloudfront distributions in the console and deploying
- only manually removing the cloudfront distribution

The current state is that I don't have any cloudfront distribution anymore in the console, but I still have the error when trying to create them...

I really need your help to understand why I have those duplicates...

Many thanks,

Comment: Well, it says in the original error message you cannot point one distribution to another. The second thing I noticed is that the ACM certificate you are trying to attach is in a region which is not `us-east-1`, which is by default where the ACM certificate should be provisioned.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoE, the thing is that i'm not pointing one distribution to the other, one is dev.mydomain while the other is app-dev.mydomain, so it shouldn't be an issue right ? Regarding Certificates, they actually are in us-east-1, but the buckets are in eu-west-3, wich shouldn't be a problem either, it's working like that if i'm forcing those parameters mannually, it's just that when trying to automate it using terraform, something doesn't work with aliases...

Comment: After some more digging, I found out that I can add the two aliases by running terraform again a few minutes after the cdn have been deployed, it would mean that creating the distribution and adding an alias can't be done simultaneously ?